# How successive cancellation decoder of polar code works in the case of BSC channel?

Tags: error-correction

fellow community members. I'd like to inquire about the decoding process of polar codes using the successive cancellation (SC) decoder, specifically for the Binary Symmetric Channel (BSC). Decoding for the Binary Erasure Channel (BEC) or Additive White Gaussian Noise (AWGN) channel is relatively straightforward, but I'm interested in understanding how the SC decoder operates for the BSC channel. If possible, it would be greatly appreciated if the explanation could include an example of a (8, 4) polar code.
Suppose the frozen bits set F={1,2,3,5} and the error probability of the BSC channel is (0.08). The receveid vector is (1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1). How we could find the transmited vector accross the BSC(0.08)?

Thank you!

Greetings, fellow community members. I'd like to inquire about the decoding process of polar codes using the successive cancellation (SC) decoder, specifically for the Binary Symmetric Channel (BSC). Decoding for the Binary Erasure Channel (BEC) or Additive White Gaussian Noise (AWGN) channel is relatively straightforward, but I'm interested in understanding how the SC decoder operates for the BSC channel. If possible, it would be greatly appreciated if the explanation could include an example of a (8, 4) polar code.

Comment: This looks more like a Theoretical Computer Science question than a programming question, and may not be able to be answered on this site.